# JavaFx : how to set image path situated in an other package

Tags: image, javafx, path

i have in my javafx project 2 packages, the first "images" is didicated to images and the second for java code ,  I want to ask you how can i set image path in this case i tried serval solution but nothing worked.

**Tried code :**

```
reg_image_statut.setImage(new Image("src/images/denided.png"));

reg_image_statut.setImage(new Image("/src/images/denided.png"));

reg_image_statut.setImage(new Image("/images/denided.png"));

reg_image_statut.setImage(new Image("../images/denided.png"));
```

**Exception getted  :**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1089)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:598)
```

**Solution:**
Yes @mipa the solution was very simple, it's exactly like you said,  the right solution was the only possiblity that i forgoted to try. Thankyou  @mipa

```
reg_image_statut.setImage(new Image("images/actived.png"));
```

Comment: Where is the image relative to your class file? When I am in doubt about the path that is used, I usually create an URL object and print out that out. The URL can then be used to load the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `src` is the source folder of your build path, you almost got it. I guess you missed this one:

```
reg_image_statut.setImage(new Image("images/denided.png"));
```

If that still does not work, you can try one of these alternatives (see [Image JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html)):

```
// The image is located in default package of the classpath
Image image1 = new Image("/flower.png");

// The image is located in my.res package of the classpath
Image image2 = new Image("my/res/flower.png");

// The image is located in the current working directory
Image image4 = new Image("file:flower.png");
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you leave it to Java to construct a correct URL which is expected by the Image constructor?

```
Image icon16 = new Image(getClass().getResource("/images/mpgafor_logo_16x16.png").toExternalForm());
```

This works for me.